# Flask API access through headers token from a Django app

Tags: flask

I'm a web dev beginner and I am trying to implement the following solution for my problem.

I have several public Flask APIs, that I need to access from a Django App. These APIs are for back-end use, with the objective to provide data from the database to the Django app access and display the data (in graphics) for the user. This strategy was build in order to separate the database from the web app for protection purposes.

I want to limit Flask APIs access in a way that just my Django app access it.

The simplest solution I came up with was creating a JWT token with SECRET_KEY information shared between applications, Flask API, and Django app, and pass the token through headers request:

**Django request:**

```
token = jwt.encode({'user_name' : 'backend_user'}, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
url = "http://website.com/api-flask"
requesturl = Request(url)
requesturl.add_header('Token', token)
response = urlopen(requesturl)
```

**Flask token check:**

```
def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = request.headers.get('Token')
        token_b = token.encode('UTF-8')

        if not token:
            return jsonify({'message' : 'No token!'}), 401

        try: 
            data = jwt.decode(token_b, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        except:
            return jsonify({'message' : 'Token is invalid!'}), 401

        return f(message, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorated


@app.route("/api-flask")
@token_required
def apiflask:
    conn = db_connect.connect()
    query = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
    result = [dict(zip(tuple (query.keys()), i)) for i in query.cursor]
    return jsonify(result)
```

Is this a good practice?
Is a secure way to do it?

Any ideas would be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: if you only want the Django app to access it then why make it public?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear. I want to restrict the APIs access for onlune Dajngo app access. I edited my question.

Comment: It's good approach until you share the secrete key and you need to give strength to the token by generating with 256 algorithm. please go through this link for more info
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/json-web-tokens-with-public-key-signatures

Comment: Thank you @dudduvenkatesh. I already improved the token.